# Change ASCII Transfer Mode To Binary

Tags: php

Is it possible to do so in PHP? Is there some function that changes the transfer mode from ASCII to binary?

Thank you.

Comment: Might want to mention that this is for FTP, just for future reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mode` argument of [`ftp_get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-get.php) and [`ftp_fget()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-fget.php) decides what mode the file transfer will be in. Use `FTP_BINARY` for binary transfers.